# Java Android ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I have two projects (A and B) that need to send data to each other.  When I try to start an activity that is in B from A, I get a ClassNotFoundException.  I think it has something to do with A and B being two separate projects.  If this is true, what needs to be done (updating the Manifest file, etc.)?  Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean two separate projects? Are they two separate apps too? Or one is a library project and the other is app project?

Comment: They are two separate applications.  Both were created as application projects.